# Unpack nested tuple in Swift closure

Tags: swift

If you have:

```
let array = [(1, 2)]
```

You can do:

```
array.map({ first, second in ... })
```

What if you have:

```
let array = [((1, 2), (3, 4))]
```

How can this be unpacked?

```
array.map({ (first, second), (third, fourth) in ... })
array.map({ ((first, second), (third, fourth)) in ... })
```

Neither of these compile.

Answer (score 0):

This works but's it's not very pretty

```
let array = [((1, 2), (3, 4))]

array.map({ a, b in
    return a.0 + a.1 + b.0 + b.1
})
```

This might be a little bit better but it's still nested

```
let array = [((1, 2), (3, 4))]

array.map({ (a:(first:Int, second:Int), b:(first:Int, second:Int)) in
    return a.first + a.second + b.first + b.second
})
```

You could use map to reduce them to a tuple and then assign the values

```
array.map{($0.0,$0.1,$1.0,$1.1)}.map { (first:Int, second:Int, third:Int, forth:Int) in }
```